# what options do I have to make my home page slider load faster

Tags: jquery, performance, slider

We are experiencing large load times for our jQuery slider at http://www.petango.com/

What options other then reducing the quality of the images do I have to speed it up you reckon?

Comment: This website require your client to have a big resolution. Maybe you should scale down images...

Comment: We'd need to see code for how you're setting it up now...

Comment: @Daok it fits in a 1024 by 768 viewport....  I feel like catering to lower resolutions than that is just a waste of time and money.

Comment: Yeah I stop designing for 800x600 ages ago.  Your welcome to view the source code.  Its using the Nivo slider

Comment: The page is slow to load for me then the slider is almost as much slow (both take more than 4 sec to load). Are you sure it's not your host?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use something like [yslow](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ninejjcohidippngpapiilnmkgllmakh), this is the chrome extension, there's also one for firebug for firefox. It will give you a lot of insightful information as to what all you can & should do to improve your page load speed.

Please [check here to see the YSlow result for your site](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/scoremeter/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.petango.com%2F&grade=D&ynumreq=18&ycdn=0&yexpires=0&ycompress=0&yjsbottom=95&ydns=85&yminify=40&yetags=0&ycookiefree=0&yimgnoscale=95&yfavicon=95).